# Error on raid 0 when modifying the 00-network-manager-all.yaml file

Tags: server, 18.04, raid, netplan

I was making a change via SSH connection on `00-network-manager-all.yaml` file on an Ubuntu Server 18.04 which is hosted on a three disk RAID0. While making the change and executing the command `sudo netplan apply` the console crashed and no longer reacted. I waited a while in case it needed time to make the change and, after a long time, I closed it because it was still not reacting. Before closing it I got the message that I had processes running.

When I tried to connect to the server, it gave me this error: `connect to host server-name port 22: Connection timed out`. I went to the server, restarted it and connected a screen and it gave me the following error:
[image]

Something that seemed strange to me was that when I opened the `00-network-manager-all.yaml` file to modify it, it was totally empty, but I thought this wasn't a problem. I've made the modifications and executed the command, as mentioned before. When I noticed the error, I tried to enter the `netplan` folder to restore the file with the backup, and found out that the `netplan` folder no longer existed.

I don't know if it has to do with the fact that I'm in a Shell and that's why it doesn't appear. I created the `netplan` folder and the `00-network-manager-all.yaml` file to see if this could solve the problem and restarted the server hoping it would work but it didn’t.

I did a lot of research but I didn’t find any forum mentioning something similar.